# Meld formerly deleted unwanted files, now sends to trash

Tags: meld

I'm running Meld from Ubuntu 16.04.3 "xenial". When I delete files, it sends them to the trash so that I'm forced to re-delete them later. My previous Meld installations didn't do this. I see nothing in Meld's Preferences menu that would allow me to get a true "delete" behavior. Has anyone else noticed this, or is it something with my system?

Answer (score 0):

I do not tested your issue. But I downgraded Meld to 1.5.3 with the following actions:

```
sudo wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/meld/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb -O /var/cache/apt/archives/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb 
sudo apt-get install -f    

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-meld
Package: meld
Pin: version 1.5.3-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

It works better for me. It has for example very useful `<Ctrl+Shift+R>` shortcut and close with `<Ctrl+Q>`.